# Xcode 6 cannot subclass UIStoryboardSegue

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

Using Xcode 6.1 I'm trying to create a left to right custom segue transition. Im following this tutorial [click here](http://blog.jambura.com/2012/07/05/custom-segue-animation-left-to-right-using-catransition/). Im stuck when changing the class NSObject to UIStoryboardSegue as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ZHCustomSegue : NSObject
// unable to change NSObject to UIStoryboardSegue
 @end
```

I get a red error saying 'cannot find interface declaration for UIStoryboardSegue'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an import to `UIKit` by either:

```
@import UIKit;
```

If you are not using modules:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```